# java.lang.StackOverflowError in a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I am currently working on an algorithm to output all permutations with a sequence of n integers and this function works fine until 6 elements, but when it is more than that I got the StackOverflowError message. I have read some questions about this topic, but what I have found out is that it happens when the recursive method has an infinite amount of calls and this seems not to be the case as its base case executes.

```
//int[] c parameter receives an array with n elemens to permute 
//int i represents the length of the sequence to permute (ai,...,aN)
public boolean isPermutated(int[] c, int i)
{
    int max = 0; // the maximum number from a sequence (a1,...,aN) and 
    int index = 0; // the index where the maximum is
    int lessThan; // an index preceded by maximum
    //Base case
    if(i == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }        
    // Gives the Maximum element from a sequence (ai,...,aN) 
    for(int count = c.length - i; count < c.length; count++)
    { 
       if(max < c[count])
       {
           max = c[count];
           index = count;
       }   
    }
    // Swap the Maximum from index to index-1
    if(max != c[c.length - i])
    {  
        lessThan = c[index-1];
        c[index-1] = max;
        c[index] = lessThan;
        //move each maximum from a sequence (a,...,aN) to the last index ex, (3,2,1)->(2,1,3)
        if(i != c.length)
        {
            while((i-c.length) != 0)
            {
                for(int count  = c.length - (i+1); count < c.length-1; count++)
                {
                    int before;
                    int after;
                    before = c[count];
                    after = c[count+1];
                    c[count] = after;
                    c[count+1] = before;     
                } 
                i++;
            }
        }

        // print array c elements    
        for(int e:c)
            System.out.print(e);
        System.out.println();
        isPermutated(c, c.length);     
    } 
    else 
    {
        i--;
        isPermutated(c, i);        
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am just frustrated as I need it with an array of 10 elements. Is there any pseudocode with the same method signature or is there any way to tweak the stack trace as that should solve partially the problem?

Comment: add code that causes error, please

Comment: Your assumptions about what's happening aren't matching reality.  Take a spin through the code in a debugger and see why it's happening.  Better yet, start writing Junit tests that exercise the class and build up complexity.

Comment: Stack overflows happen when the call stack is overflown, which is caused by a finite number of calls, not an infinite number of calls.

Comment: If your stack size is exceeded by the number of recursive calls you get a `StackOverflowException`. The exact stack size depends on the JVM and its settings so we can't tell you what recursion depth is too big. If your code doesn't do any unnecessary recursions (check that with a debugger) and you still get a stack overflow then either reduce your problem size or rewrite your algorithm to a non-recursive version.

Comment: I always get a stack overflow when I write recursive methods that don't execute the stopping condition.  Guaranteed that yours is flawed.

Comment: Lesson number one in programming: do not trust your **assumptions** more than your **observations**. If you get a Stackoverflow exception, then 99,999% chance that your recursion doesn't stop. Besides: One reason why you have so much trouble understanding what is going on: this code is really not "clean at all". That one method is doing a **lot of things**, and it shouldn't. Besides: such functions are **perfect** for TDD and unit testing. Write small test, and small pieces of your function; and you will not end up with one huge monster function that is **hard** to understand and debug.

Comment: What should the algorithm do, exactly?

Comment: the code never return true that was the problem

Comment: @AdriaanKoster should be a recursive method to produce all permutation from n elements

Comment: @duffymo, OP says that his implementation, "works fine until 6 elements."  If it works for an array of six elements, then it probably is not wrong, but if it blows the stack for seven elements, then it probably is not a very good design.  I don't have time for a deep look, but I bet that the problem is here:  `isPermutated(c, c.length);`  I bet the program is using recursion to handle a case that could have been handled by iterating instead.

Comment: I don't believe the OP.  AFAIK, any iterative process can be written as recursive and visa versa.

Comment: @duffymo, Maybe you're right.  I don't have time to look any deeper.

Comment: So what is the parameter `i` for then?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster actually I missed to explain it, this parameter is used to work with another sequence that is why the base solution is when the sequence is just of one element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't your code miss return statements ? Why do you call isPermutated without worrying about the retruned value ?

Your code never returns true.